# I am making a c++ code and error occurs I don't know why

Tags: c++, vector, console, codeblocks

don't know where my problem is. I tried to compile the code once and it worked. However, I copied it in a new project in order to modify it, just the colour or the time to wait, and it just works in the first programme. What is wrong? I feel really frustrated. With this code I want to graphic the sine function. Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t,n1,n2,res=0;
    cin>>t;
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    while (t--) {
        cin>>n1>>n2;
        v1.push_back(n1);
        v2.push_back(n2);
    }
    for (int i=v1.size();i>0;i++) {
        bool state=binary_search(v2.begin(),v2.end(),v1[i-1]);
        if (state){
            v1.pop_back();
            res++;
        }
    }
    cout<<res<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[error of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Ypm.png)

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` Don't do that!

Comment: Take a look at your `for` loop. Does it ever evaluate to false?

Comment: Sure about these conditions in your for loop? `for (int i=v1.size();i>0;i++){`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
for (int i=v1.size();i>0;i++)
```

To

```
for (int i=v1.size();i>0;i--)
```

Otherwise you would access behind the bounds -> *UB*.

Or even to another segment in memory -> *SIGSEGV*.

---

Also [std::binary_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) says:

> *"... A **fully-sorted** range meets these criteria."*

So before calling `binary-search` you have to do

```
std::sort (v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the for statement

```
for (int i=v1.size();i>0;i++) {
                         ^^^
```

It is evident that you mean instead

```
for (int i=v1.size();i>0;i--) {
                         ^^^
```

It is better to write the for statement like

```
for ( auto i = v1.size(); i != 0; i-- ) {
      ^^^^
```

However in any case the program is wrong.

First of all before using the method `std::binary_search`  you have to sort the vector `v2`.

The second problem is that this call

```
v1.pop_back();
```

does not necessary remove the element of the vector `v1` that is found in the vector `v2`. It can just remove the last element of the vector `v1` that even is not present in the vector `v2`.